# Como remover um "item" do último registro?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso que o último registro não mostre o `<div class="staffClearFix"></div>`

```
<?php 
    $userdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank = '9' AND status = 'Ativo' ORDER BY id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userdata)){
?>
    <?php echo $row['username']; ?>
    <div class="staffClearFix"></div>   
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverta a ordem e adicione uma lógica para excluir do primeiro registro que ficará mais fácil:

```
$first = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userdata)) {
   if (!$first) 
   {
       echo '<div class="staffClearFix"></div>';
   }

   echo $row['username'];

   $first = false;
}
```

Outro detalhe, não utilize funções [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) elas estão obsoletas desde a versão 5.5 e removidas no PHP 7. Utilize [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) ou [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Comment: Mas eu preciso remover do último, não da pra inverter :(

Comment: Você testou o código? Ele irá fazer exatamente o que você solicitou.

Comment: Perdão, estava meio que colocando ele errado aqui... Funcionou sim! Você poderia me explicar como funciona ele? Não entendi direito como este código funciona, gostaria de aprender.

Comment: @CarlosG Basicamente, ele irá colocar a `div` sempre antes do nome, exceto se for o primeiro nome. Então, no primeiro nome, não haverá a div antes do nome. Já, no segundo nome, haverá a div antes do nome. E ficará assim: (nome | div | nome). E assim por diante.